# How I Can Merge Mutiple Rows into One in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
ID   col1   col2   col3 
------------------------
1     A     null   null 
1    null    B     null 
1    null   null    C 
2     D     null   null 
2    null    E     null 
2    null   null    F
```

From this table, remove null value and merge rows base on ID

```
ID   col1   col2  col3 
------------------------
1     A      B     C 
2     D      E     F
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use aggregation for that, as aggregate functions ignore NULL values:

```
select id, 
       max(col1) as col1, 
       max(col2) as col2,
       max(col3) as col3
from the_table
group by id
order by id;
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=bf85a6a9ed09067d29eb6bfa03ed5eca)

Comment: Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Column 'dbo.TempTable4.LC' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: @MehdiAliAkbari: the query from my answer can not result in that error

Comment: i want to select diameter of the table, u can see every row hav 1 value and 2 null

Comment: @MehdiAliAkbari: apparently your real problem/question isn't what you put into your question. This query answers exactly what you have asked. If you want something different, then you should have asked a different question

Comment: please take a look to my second Table

Comment: @MehdiAliAkbari: this query generates exactly that output: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=bf85a6a9ed09067d29eb6bfa03ed5eca